# file formatting using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

My input file contains data in the following format:

```
1503668542862176    manager=10001|Bounced=999|Analyst=10004|Business Analyst=10005|Programmer=10003
1552024948590636    manager=10001|Bounced=999|Analyst=10004
1551728916565460    Bounced=999|Analyst=10004
1553617087089790    Analyst=10004
1538058487418963    manager=10001|Architect=10002|Analyst=10004
```

I have to convert second column where every pair of `key=value` should be double quoted as `"key"="value"` and `|` should be replaced with `,` as below using `awk`.

```
1503668542862176    "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004","Business Analyst"="10005","Programmer"="10003"
1552024948590636    "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1551728916565460    "Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1553617087089790    "Analyst"="10004"
1538058487418963    "manager"="10001","Architect"="10002","Analyst"="10004"
```

Comment: Can you clarify what constitutes a “key value”?  Is “Apollo13” one value or two? How about “Maroon 5”? How about “read-only”, “read/write”, “I.B.M.” and “Unix & Linux”?

Comment: Fisrt column is a number and second column is Key Value pair ... where before = is Key and after = is Value.

Comment: Is the first and second column delimited by a tab?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e 's/|/","/g' -e 's/=/"="/g' -e 's/\t/\t"/' -e 's/$/"/' input.txt
```

This will:

- replace any `|` with `,`
- replace any `=` with `"="`
- replace the first tab stop with `\t"`
- append a `"`and the line end

The most easiest way with `awk` is to change to field separators:

```
$ awk -v FS="|" -v OFS='","' '{$1=$1}1' \
  | awk -v FS="=" -v OFS='"="' '{$1=$1}1'\
  | awk -v FS="\t" '{print $1,"\""$2"\""}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but can you please help with AWK

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: You're right. Have edited the answer.

Comment: but we don't know field separator is Tab  :  )

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/|/","/g;s/=/"="/g;s/ /"/4;s/$/"/g' file

1503668542862176   "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004","Business Analyst"="10005","Programmer"="10003"
1552024948590636   "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1551728916565460   "Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1553617087089790   "Analyst"="10004"
1538058487418963   "manager"="10001","Architect"="10002","Analyst"="10004"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use GNU awk (which is typically available on any standard Linux distribution), you can use sub-expressions with the `gensub()` function:

```bash
< input_data awk -- '{gsub("\\|", ","); print gensub("([[:alpha:]][^=]*)=([^,]+)", "\"\\1\"=\"\\2\"", "g")}'
```

Assuming `|` appears only as key-value-pair separator, the first `gsub()` converts each `|` in `,` and then the `gensub()` function does the rest.

If you must use a POSIX awk then you may still obtain the same with a single script using a sequence of (indeed awkward..) `gsub()`s:

```bash
< input_data awk -- '{gsub("=", "\""); gsub("([[:alpha:]][^\"]*)", "\"&\"="); gsub("\"[^|]*", "&\""); gsub("\\|", ","); print;}'
```

Broken down (only the `awk` script part):

```awk
{
    gsub("=", "\"");
    gsub("([[:alpha:]][^\"]*)", "\"&\"=");
    gsub("\"[^|]*", "&\"");
    gsub("\\|", ",");
    print;
}
```

The first `gsub()` replaces each `=` into a `"`, paving the way for the subsequent couple of `gsub()`s, the first one looking for keys up to (but excluding) the first `"` and replacing that whole string with a leading `"` plus the found key plus a trailing `"=`, and the second `gsub()` looking for values starting with `"` (which originally was the `=`) up to (but excluding) the first `|` (if present) and replacing that string with itself plus a trailing `"`.

Basically this second solution uses `"` as ancillary key-value separator, therefore requires that it does not appear in either keys or values.

The final `gsub()` replaces all `|` in `,` just as in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a sleek regular expression, or you could do it by parsing the fields, splitting them on the appropriate delimiters, and reconstructing them in the way you want using `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    # Assume the two fields are tab-delimited.
    OFS = FS = "\t"
}

NF > 1 {
    # Split the 2nd field into sub-fields on "|" in the array a.
    n = split($2, a, "|")

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        # Split each sub-field on "=" and quote the two bits,
        # and put them together again.
        if (split(a[i], b, "=") == 2)
            a[i] = sprintf("\"%s\"=\"%s\"", b[1], b[2])
        else {
            # Bail out on bad fields.
            print >"/dev/stderr"
            printf("Error in field %d on line %d\n", i, FNR) >"/dev/stderr"
            exit 1
        }

    # Reconstruct current record.
    $0 = $1
    $2 = a[1]

    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        $2 = $2 "," a[i]

    # Done, output
    print
}
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
1503668542862176        "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004","Business Analyst"="10005","Programmer"="10003"
1552024948590636        "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1551728916565460        "Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1553617087089790        "Analyst"="10004"
1538058487418963        "manager"="10001","Architect"="10002","Analyst"="10004"
```

Answer (score -1):

Done by awk command

command:

```
awk '{gsub(/\|/,",",$0);print $0}' filename | awk '{$2="\""$2;print $0}'| awk '{gsub(/\=/,"\"=\"",$0);print $0}'| awk '{gsub(/\,/,"\",\"",$0);print $0}'| awk '{$NF=$NF"\"";print $0}'
```

output

```
 awk '{gsub(/\|/,",",$0);print $0}' filename| awk '{$2="\""$2;print $0}'| awk '{gsub(/\=/,"\"=\"",$0);print $0}'| awk '{gsub(/\,/,"\",\"",$0);print $0}'| awk '{$NF=$NF"\"";print $0}'

1503668542862176 "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004","Business Analyst"="10005","Programmer"="10003"
1552024948590636 "manager"="10001","Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1551728916565460 "Bounced"="999","Analyst"="10004"
1553617087089790 "Analyst"="10004"
1538058487418963 "manager"="10001","Architect"="10002","Analyst"="10004"
```